# unexpected 'if' (T_IF)

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente codigo

```
$data .= '<tr>
            <td>'.$number.'</td> 
            <td>'.$row['nombre'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['apellido'].'</td>
            <td>'.$estado.'</td>
            <td>
                <button onclick="GetUserDetails('.$row['id'].')" class="btn btn-warning">Update</button>
            </td>
            <td>'.if( $estado == 5){.'  



                <button onclick="DeleteUser('.$row['id'].')" class="btn btn-success">Iniciar</button>       

'.}.'
                <button onclick="DeleteUser('.$row['id'].')" class="btn btn-warning">Iniciar</button>   


            </td>
        </tr>';
```

pero no me agarra la etiqueta `if`, esto esta dentro de las etiquetas `<?php` correspondientes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes cambiarlo a una condición ternaria:

```
$data .= '<tr>
            <td>'.$number.'</td> 
            <td>'.$row['nombre'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['apellido'].'</td>
            <td>'.$estado.'</td>
            <td>
                <button onclick="GetUserDetails('.$row['id'].')" class="btn btn-warning">Update</button>
            </td>
            <td>'.(($estado == 5) ? '

                <button onclick="DeleteUser('.$row['id'].')" class="btn btn-success">Iniciar</button>       

' : '').'
                <button onclick="DeleteUser('.$row['id'].')" class="btn btn-warning">Iniciar</button>   


            </td>
        </tr>';
```

Documentación [operaciones ternarias](http://php.net/manual/es/language.operators.comparison.php)

Comment: MUCHAS GRACIAS SOS UN GENIO !!

Comment: Excelente que te haya funcionado

Answer (score 6):

El error es porque tienes un `if` (que es un constructor) unido (con el ".") a la variable `$data` (que es un *string* / cadena de caracteres). Puedes corregirlo cerrando el string y a continuación ejecutando el "if":

```
$data = '<tr>...
    <td>';
if ($estado == 5) {
    $data.= '<button ...>';
}
$data.= '</td></tr>';
```

Comment: Muchas gracias !!